# Openni in groovy: Error when trying to launch openni_tracker

Tags: kinect, openni, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS and just managed to install Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04. After installing the openni packages I'm able to receive the disparity and RGB image from my Kinect, but if I want to start the skeleton tracker by calling
`rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker`, I just get the error

```
[ERROR] [1360932563.459904042]: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

Has anybody ever experienced the same error and knows how to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55289/openni-in-groovy:-error-when-trying-to-launch-openni_tracker/) by [dinsn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4211/dinsn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.10, ROS Groovy.

I had a bit of trouble downloading the correct version of NITE.

The first couple of time I tried:

1. OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.4.0.tar.zip
2. NiTE-Linux-x64-2.0.0.tar1.zip

Both of which had no uninstall.sh files. Only the install.sh file.

Finally, I found [NITE-Bin-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.21.tar.zip]
(http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/NITE-Bin-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.21.tar.zip)

This last version had the uninstall file. After running it as sudo and then running the install.sh file, everything worked.

---

Originally posted by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) with karma: 208 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0